# Access controllers $scope and $route in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, routes

I have site navigation that contains a lot of reused code, and I'm trying to create some custom directives to use instead.

There's quite a bit of logic in the navigation to apply various css rules, change attributes etc.

```
<a ng-href="/#/Discovery" class="header" 
ng-class="{active_header: $route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length == 1, keep_open: $route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length > 0}">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i><span translate="reports.discovery.discovery"></span>
</a>

<a class="menu_toggle" data-target="#discovery_menu" 
ng-class="{disabled_toggle: $route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length == 2, enabled_toggle: $route.current.details[0].tab != 'discovery' || $route.current.details.length != 2}"
ng-attr-data-toggle="{{($route.current.details[0].tab != 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length > 0) || ($route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length == 1) ? 'collapse' : ''}}"
ng-attr-tooltip-enable="{{$route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length == 2 ? 'true' : 'false'}}"
tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" uib-tooltip="{{'tooltips.navopen' | translate}}">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

The navigation has it's own controller, which uses $scope and $route and sets

```
$scope.$route = $route;
```

that is used in the nav as you see it above to check the current route.

I have managed to create a custom directive for the first part, the a tag with the class of 'header' and it works great (fyi, using typescript)

```
export class parentTab {
    public static Factory() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                route: '=',
                tabName: '@',
                icon: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/navigation/parentTab.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.$parent.current);
            }
        }
    }
}

// used in html
<parent-tab route="$route" tab-name="discovery" icon="search"></parent-tab>
```

The template file is simply the same html code it was before, but using '{{tabName}}' where 'discovery' would be for example.

The problem I'm having is creating a directive for the second and largest part (I have thought I may be able to use one directive for both, but as I'm learning I thought it best to separate them into two for now and combine later).

The problem occurs when I hit the ng-attr attributes, for example enabling the tooltip:

```
ng-attr-tooltip-enable="{{$route.current.details[0].tab == 'discovery' && $route.current.details.length == 2 ? 'true' : 'false'}}"
```

I can't replace 'discovery' with '{{tabName}} because the entire thing is wrapped in {{}}, if I try that I get:

```
Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 33-43 ['{{tabName] in expression [(route.current.details[0].tab == '{{tabName]
```

I've tried removing the outer {{}}, which doesn't work.

From here I thought the best option was to perform this logic in the directive itself, but I've discovered my problem is now accessing $scope.$route as it is set on the Navigation controller. Here is the directive for menu_toggle (very similar to parentTab):

```
export class menuToggle {
    public static Factory() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                route: '=',
                tabName: '@',
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log(scope.route);
            },
            templateUrl: '/app/templates/navigation/menuToggle.html'
        }
    }
}
```

That console.log results in an object of routes, containing all the routes in the application, being logged out. Nowhere does it have access to the current route or the details array which is set on each route, e.g.

```
.when('/Discovery', <any> {
  controller: 'DiscoveryController',
  details: [
    {path: '/Discovery', tab: 'discovery'}
  ]
})
```

If I could just access the $scope and/or the $route from the Navigation controller I think I'd be fine from there, but I can't seem to get access at all. I've read various things online and googled to the end of the Earth.

I hope there's someone out there who can help... thanks, I also appreciate this has been a very long question so I hope it has made sense what I am trying to do, thanks for reading if you've made it this far.
(I'm working in a 2 man team on this project, if you're wondering where the advanced stuff may have come from that's the other guy - I'm still learning and getting to grips with all this stuff.)

**Update:**
I made a test directive that's just an attribute,

```
export class testRel {
    public static Factory() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '{{$route.current.details[0].tab}}',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // console.log(scope.$route);
                // console.log(scope.$route.current.details[0].tab);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The template part, {{$route.current.details[0].tab}}, works and displays the current tab on the page, but again I can't access this in the link where I assume I would need to do the logic?

If I console.log the route in the link function, I get a route object logged out that has a 'current' object inside it with the relevant information I need, I just can't seem to get to it when I try to console.log it.

**Update 2:**
I've managed to access $route.current now by using a setTimeout function with the console.log - the next step is to try and use the logic from this directive with the directive that creates the actual template.

I'll keep updating as I go, who knows I may have an answer myself eventually... but please feel free to offer your 2 cents :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this working eventually - maybe this may be of help to someone else one day.

I discovered that I could create a controller on the testRel directive, and access this controller in the directives link function.

So in testRel's controller I had a simple function that set variables I wanted it to, for example

```
controller: function() {
  this.tab;
  this.setTab = function(tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
  }
}
```

And then, in my link function I can access the setTab function like so:

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs, testRelCtrl) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    menuToggleLogicCtrl.setTab('tabname here');
  }, 0);
}
```

The next step swas using this data in my parentTab directive.
I came along the 'require' attribute of directives which allows you to link two directives together (or multiple, like a daisy chain) and access its data.

I require the directive and then link the data inside the link function.

```
return {
  require: '^testRel',
  scope: {
    ....
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, testRelCtrl) {
    scope.testRelCtrl = testRelCtrl;
  }
}
```

With all this I can set booleans and variables etc then access them in the directives template using

```
{{ testRelCtrl.whateverIWant }}
```

Btw, I set the testRel directive to just be an attribute, and the parentTab directive to be an element, now wherever I want to use it I just have to have

```
<parent-tab test-rel></parent-tab>
```

along with any attributes with data I pass in that are set in the scope of the directive.